# Find adjacent values from a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

The previous post was just a simplified example. My problem is with the following worksheet:

So, there is a list of equipment(inventory number) that repeats for every month and year, and there is a row (underline in yellow) with the days of the month. Bellow each day of the month there are four columns, I need to extract the biggest value of Km/hours (underline in in red) for a given inventory number. I was able to extract the previous with the maxifs function inside a max function.

The second part is where I need help; how to extract the date (dd/mm/yy) where the biggest value of km/hours occurs for each inventary number, need to concatenate the values of year, month and day in one cell.

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDmX5.png)

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `VLOOKUP` or maybe `INDEX/MATCH` but it's hard to be sure without some sample data and expected outcome

Comment: are the amounts unique?

Comment: You want to say for 1800 what is the Width & Height !!

Comment: Toto, your recent edit has changed the Object of the OP for what I've posted the possible solution.

Comment: @Tpint0, welcome to Super User.  Something to consider for future reference: you can ask more than one question.  Put some thought into the question before posting to try to make it as clear as possible.  Once it attracts answers, it generally isn't fair to the responders to radically change the question to invalidate the answers.  If people interpreted the question in ways you hadn't anticipated, that happens; clarify it.  But don't post a simplified version first and then replace it with a different version after receiving answers.  In that case, ask a new question with the new version.

Comment: @fixer1234, well noted. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest two different solution to extract Row & Column headings for the given value.*

**Solution one** can be used when search data range has *Unique values*.

**Solution two** can be used when search data rage has *Duplicate values*.

**Solution 1:**

[image]

**How it works:**

1. In Cell `G1` write search value.
2. To get Row heading write this formula in Cell `G3`.

   ```
   =INDEX(A2:A6,SUMPRODUCT((B2:F6=G1)*(ROW(B2:F6)-ROW(B2)+1)))
   ```
3. To get Column heading write this formula in Cell `G5`.

   ```
   =INDEX(B1:F1,SUMPRODUCT((B2:F6=G1)*(COLUMN(B1:F1)-COLUMN(B1)+1)))
   ```

**Solution 2:**

[image]

**How it works:**

1. Two *helper columns* need to be created. 
   First in `Column G` & Second in `Column H`.
2. Write this formula in Cell `G2` & fill down.

   ```
     =LARGE(B2:F2,1)
   ```
3. Write this in Cell `H2` & fill down.

   ```
     =MATCH(G2,B2:F2,0)
   ```
4. Formula in Cell `B8` & fill down.

   ```
     =LARGE($G$2:$G$6,ROW(A1))
   ```
5. Formula in Cell `C8` & fill it down.

   ```
    =INDEX($G$2:$H$6,MATCH(B8,$G$2:$G$6,0),2)
   ```
6. Formula in Cell `A8` & fill it  down.

   ```
    =INDEX($A$2:$A$6,MATCH(B8,$G$2:$G$6,0),1)
   ```

**Note,** *adjust cell references in the formula 
       as needed.*

Comment: hello Rajesh, Taking in consideration the edit i´ve made to the post, how can I change solution 1 to work with my worksheet? thanks in advance

Comment: @Tpint0, plz edit  the post and upload the sample data so that  I can redesign my answer. ☺

Comment: I edit the post and add some sample data. thank you.